Problem in deploying django app using plesk
I am trying to deploy my django app and i am using plesk as a host.
But i have 2 problems

In order to reach the website instead of
typing mydomain/login  i have to type mydomain/templates/login.html

The page appears broken as the picture below.



I have checked and collected the static files and the urls seem fine. I don't understand what i am missing.
I would appreciate a helping hand!
Thank you

You're probably exposing your templates. You shouldn't be accessing these as it shows your code. Normally, you should be using wsgi or asgi to run your python code. Have you followed a tutorial like this one: https://www.plesk.com/blog/guides/django-hosting-latest-plesk-onyx/

I have both files in my directory... and the i also contacted plesk support to check the cofigurations and told me that they are fine ...
